# Civicrm Version Upgrade 5.64.4 Error Message

Tags: upgrade, error, error-page

I recently did an upgrade for my civicrm site to 5.64.4. However I have been facing this error when I am trying to click a contact.
[image: Error message]

There is more details to the error here:
[image]

Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: Check if CiviContribute extension is enabled and CiviContribute component is enabled.

Comment: Yes both the extension and component is enabled

Comment: Might help to post the full backtrace in that case.